# Find conditional expectation from a 3-dimensional random vector?

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics, conditional-expectation

I have a three-dimensional random vector $Y$ ~ $N(\mu , \Sigma)$ whose moment-generating function is:

$M_Y(t_1,t_2,t_3)=exp(2t_1+3t_2-3t_3+4t_1^2+5t_2^2+3t_3^2-t_1t_2+2t_1t_3)$.

It was easy to calculate $\mu$

because
$M_Y(t)=exp(\mu^Tt+\frac12 t^T\Sigma t), \mu_1 = 2, \mu_2 = 3, \mu_1 = -3.$

Also, $\Sigma=\left[\matrix{8&-1&2 \\ -1&10&0 \\ 2&0&6}\right]$. (If there was any wrong points in this calculation, please let me know).

This is what I have done now....

However, I know only how to calculate the conditional mean when the vector is two-dimentional: $E[Y_1|Y_2=y_2]=E[Y_1]+\Sigma_{12}\Sigma_{22}^{-1}(y_2-\mu_2)$

$VAR[Y_1|Y_2=y_2]=\Sigma_{11}-\Sigma_{12}\Sigma_{22}^{-1}\Sigma_{21}$
(* May anyone let me know the process of having the inverse of covariance in the $\Sigma$?)

For 3D, I still did not get good idea how to calculate $E[Y_1|Y_2=y_2, Y_3=y_3] $ and $VAR[Y_1|Y_2=y_2, Y_3=y_3]$.

For example: $E[Y_1|Y_2=\frac72, Y_3=-2] $ and $VAR[Y_1|Y_2=\frac72, Y_3=-2]$. How is the process changing compared to a 2D one, and where should I start?

Comment: lookup the wikipedia article, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Conditional_distributions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partition the $\Sigma$ matrix as required. If you are interested in the conditional distribution of $Y_{1}$ given $\left(\begin{array}{c}
Y_{2}\\
Y_{3}\\
\end{array}\right)$, then the partition the covariance matrix as

\begin{equation*}
\Sigma = \left(
\begin{array}{c|cc}
8 &-1& 2\\
\hline
-1& 10& 0\\
2& 0&  6\\
\end{array}\right)
\end{equation*}
Identify this partition as
\begin{equation*}
\Sigma = \left(
\begin{array}{c|c}
\Sigma_{11} & \Sigma_{12}\\
\hline
\Sigma_{21}& \Sigma_{22}\\
\end{array}\right)
\end{equation*}
where $\Sigma_{11}=8$, $\Sigma_{12}=(-1\;\; 2)$, $\Sigma_{21}=\left(\begin{array}{c}
-1\\
2
\end{array}\right)$ and $\Sigma_{22}=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
10 & 0\\
0& 6\\
\end{array}\right)$
Find the inverse of $\Sigma_{22}$ and plug-in the values into your expressions.