# Middle entries of a random vector - Conditional expectation and covariance matrix of normal distribution P(X2|X1, X3)

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics, conditional-expectation

Let us consider the random vector $X=[X_1,X_2,X_3]$, which follows a multivariate normal distribution. That is, for each entry $X_i$: $X_i \sim N(\mu_i, \Sigma_i)$.

What I am trying to compute is the expectation $\mu_{X_2|X_1, X_3}$ and covariance matrix  $\Sigma_{X_2|X_1, X_3}$ of $P(X_2|X_1, X_3)$.

I've seen some very nice posts and answers on how to compute the conditional expectation and covariance matrix of $P(X_1|X_2, X_3)$ ([for instance this one](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/239317/find-conditional-expectation-from-a-3-dimensional-random-vector?rq=1&newreg=3ab02a82c6b24504a855431ed833ff42)) and $P(X_3|X_1, X_2)$, but not for $P(X_2|X_1, X_3)$.

Am I missing something? It would be great to have some insights or references on what happens when we look at conditional expectations of the middle entries of a random vector!

Comment: just switch the order of your Rvs (also in $\mu,\Sigma$), and use the same results

Comment: Alternatively, follow *exactly* the procedure in the duplicate but partition the matrix to isolate the second variable rather than the third.

Comment: @whuber I wasn't sure how to do the partition though, hence the question.

Comment: And @gunes, yes exactly. I had done that but wasn't sure whether that would be correct. Thanks!

Comment: One way to do the partition is to reorder the components so that $X_2$ appears first!